# How to mix RDMS DB with a Graph DB

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, graph-databases

I am developing a website using **Django**, and **PostgreSQL** which would seemingly have huge amount of data as gathered in social network sites.

I need to use RDMS with SQL for tabular data for less SQL complexity **and** also Graph DB with Cipher for large data for high query complexity.

Please let me know how to go about this. Also please let me know whether it is feasible.

EDIT: Clarity as asked in Comments:-
The database structure can be similar to that of a social network like Facebook. I've checked FB Engineering page for their open graph. For graph DB I can find only Neo4J graph DB with proper ACID values though I would prefer an open source graph DB. Graph DB structure, I require basically for summary of huge volume data pertaining to relationships like friends, updates, daily user related updates as individual relations. Horizontal Scalability is important for future up gradation to me.

I intend to use PostgreSQL for base informational data and push the relational data updates to graph DB like Facebook uses both MySql and open graph.

Comment: Maybe you could add a few more details and you might get more attention. What sort of structure do you have in mind for your graph DB ? Do you need conversion from SQL to graph ? Do you have a graph DB in mind? Is horizontal scalability important to you ?

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira The database structure can be similar to that of a social network like Facebook. For graph DB I can find only Neo4J graph DB with proper ACID values though I would prefer an open source graph DB. Graph DB structure I require basically for summary of huge volume data pertaining to relationships like friends,  updates. Horizontal Scalability is important for future up gradation to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my queries. I would first suggest looking at [TitanDB](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/). I believe it fulfills many of your requirements:

1. It is open source.
2. It scales horizontally.

In addition to meeting your requirements it has existed for quite sometime and many companies are using it in Production. The only thing you would have to get used to is that it uses [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/) traversals, not Cypher queries. Also note that I believe Titan is not ACID for most backends. This is a result of it being horizontally scalable.

If you would like a more structured (but significantly less mature) approach to Graph DBs then you can look at the stack that myself and some colleagues are working on [MindmapsDB](https://mindmaps.io/) which sits on top of Titan, but uses a more "sql-like" query language.

[OrientDB Gremlin](https://github.com/mpollmeier/orientdb-gremlin) is also a very good option but lacks the maturity and support of Titan.

There are many other graph vendors out there such as DSE Graph, IBM Graph, etc . . . but the ones I have listed above are the opensource ones I have worked with.

Comment: The Tinkerpop 2 side of [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) could also be a good option but I have not used it and cannot comment on how good it may be.

Comment: I would through your listed DBs and check implementation

Comment: I've marked this as answer as it helped me. And it was the only answer also :P

Answer (score 0):

Use PostgreSQL for tabular data (profiles, posts) and Neo4j for graph data (relationships, social connections). Sync data via triggers/tasks. Optimize queries: PostgreSQL for simple, Neo4j's Cypher for complex. Scalability via sharding/replication. Cache for performance. Regularly optimize. Maintain consistency during data transfer.